# Linker error with constexpr static member variable

Tags: c++, templates, static, linker, constexpr

I would appreciate some explanation why does the following code produces the compilation error:
`undefined reference to sinet::testtable'`
Here is the actual code:

```
#define TABLE_SIZE 2000
template<class Function, std::size_t... Indices>
constexpr static auto make_array_helper(Function f, std::index_sequence<Indices...>) 
-> std::array<typename std::result_of<Function(std::size_t)>::type, sizeof...(Indices)> 
{
    return {{ f(Indices)... }};
}

template<int N, class Function>
constexpr static auto make_array(Function f)
-> std::array<typename std::result_of<Function(std::size_t)>::type, N> 
{
    return make_array_helper(f, std::make_index_sequence<N>{});    
}
constexpr static float fun(double x) { return (float)sin(((double)x / (double)TABLE_SIZE) * M_PI * 2.0); }

class sinet{

public:
    constexpr static auto testtable = make_array<TABLE_SIZE>(fun);
};
```

The code is supposed to fill a static array at compile time, and it does work as long as the `constexpr static array` isnt a member.

If I initialize the static member as a single float, it works , as in no linker errors. But why?

There were a lot of similar questions to this, but i could not discern an answer specific to my example.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Thanks to djrollins's answer, I now know that the static memeber could not be evaluated as constexpr because sin can not be either.

Which is unfortunate, as all this was for initializing a static array at compile time, but it seems that is impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`constexpr static` members can only be initialised inside the class body if the initialiser is also `constexpr`.

Your `fun` function contains a call to `sin` which, like most of the standard maths functions, is not `constexpr`.

Comment: Sadly this still gets me errors: `declaration of ‘const auto sinet::testtable’ has no initializer` and `‘testtable’ in ‘class sinet’ does not name a type` I would say this was impossible, but if i take the initialization out of a class it **works**, creating a static global array.